# Qt sdk1.1 == 1.5GB. Why So Huge?

Tags: qt

I've been searching for this info with no luck.  I'm using SDK1 with 4.7.0.  Works fine but has some issues with Postres so I need to update.  The thing is...

I go to download RC SDK1.1 and I see windows version is 1.5GB!! 
The Linux version is about 700MB.

Why is Win version more than double?

SDK1 was about 320MB for windows and 400MB+ for Linux.

So Windows version was relatively smaller than Linux version considerably and sdk1 was drastically smaller than sdk1.1.  I hear that 1.5GB unpacks to 5GB.

Of course, if you download the framework and creator separately than it is normal size (roughly equivalent to SDK1).  This just adds to confusion.  Isn't the SDK == Framework + creator ?

Something is wrong here... Any ideas what is going on?  Should I wait till full release version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats because only Windows supports development for Symbian platform using Symbian SDK that can be installed (other platforms use remote compiler). Nokia with Qt SDK 1.1 announcement mentioned that they refactored Symbian toolchains so now you can use Symbian ^ 1 and Symbian ^ 3 native APIs. I think that what made the installer so huge. On the web site I noticed they have web installer, so I'd recommend to download the web installer which is just 15Mb and I suppose it should be a wizzard page that allows you to select which parts to install. Just don't install Symbian native SDK or anything else you don't need.

Hope that helps